# Ruby: Stop displaying IP in Error output

Tags: ruby, ip, hide, editing

Have a bot that when it relays a connection error it reveals the server IP, which could cause security problems. Wanting to eliminate the output of the IP when the error is conducted, anyone have any ideas?

Where the Host IP is outputted to the error:

> Connection refused(2)= Connect to "Host IP" port 45443.

My code:

```
module Bitcoin
  class Client
    def self.local
      return Bitcoin::Client.new(ENV['RPC_USER'], ENV['RPC_PASSWORD'],
        { host: 'Host IP', port: 45443, ssl: false} )
    end
  end
end
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, your question is not clear, in the code you pasted, you are just creating new class. I don't see the code which is making network connection, you need to add that code, or, if you using some bitcoin library, paste link to it.

Comment: @rubycut https://github.com/samgos/Reddbot/blob/master/tipper.rb , that's the only other place it is inputted basically but depending on the type of error. It origins from ruby i'm pretty sure .

Answer (score 1):

Just rescue from that error and raise your own error with a custom message instead:

```
module Bitcoin
  class Client
    def self.local
      Bitcoin::Client.new(
        ENV['RPC_USER'], ENV['RPC_PASSWORD'],
        { host: 'Host IP', port: 45443, ssl: false} 
      )
    rescue StandardError
      raise "Unable to connect to Bitcoin"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: results with this :(                                                                                       Error: Connection refused - connect(2) for "Host IP" port 45443
    /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize'

Comment: Sorry, according to [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/tenderlove/245188) it seems to be the best solution to rescue from `StandardError` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the link you passed, you can isolate specific Exception types and what will happen when they are raised:

```
begin
  command = Command.new(params)
  command.perform
  json command.result

rescue NetworkError
  json text: "Custom message without ip", icon_emoji: ":large_blue_circle:"

rescue Exception => ex
  json text: "Error: #{ex.message}", icon_emoji: ":large_blue_circle:"
end
```

Comment: Problem is this is for various errors, tried @spickermanns approach to no avail even when integrating it to this statement .

Comment: You can try inspecting the exception when you get connection error. Then you can escape only this error. I'll update my answer.